# Load php script to run with cron

Tags: php, email, cron

First, apologize for my English.

I am creating a script for my web subscription. This script will run with a cron but I doubt emerges.

My host has a limit of 25 emails every 2 minutes, 200 emails per hour, and the php max_execution_time configuration is 120. The script should send 6 emails every minute. Because of this limutaciójn, I get the time it takes to run the script and do a sleep time to 1 minute remaining, so do not like to do is to reload the script with the new parameters sent using GET.

When a script run by cron, I can not use javascript or header location, so do not really know how to make this script will reload with the new parameters.

Does anyone have any idea, please?

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to come up with a good answer.  If you launch the script using GET variables, what supplies those variables?  A MySQL database?  An Excel spreadsheet on your workstaion?  A PHP array?  Make your question more complete, and the answers will be more complete.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917251/php-email-and-cron ... though at this point I don't know if your problem is with the basic programming or the strategy for adapting to your provider's limits.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I mean.
The process is as follows, users subscribe to a subscription list, and creates web administrator to mail to this list. I have a database that stores everything. 24:00 When they get the mails are sent to users.

Comment: The cron would run at 24:00, and what they would do the first time would be to read the ID of the mail has been sent, and the number of subscribers. Due to restrictions, it should send 6 emails every 2 minutes, so the script will read the first 6 users, send them mail and wait two minutes. When just two minutes, the script will call itself passing the data through GET (email id, the last user who sent you the mail, total subscribers).

Comment: El problema es que no se como hacer que el script se llame asi mismo con los nuevos parametros enviados por GET, porque al ser un cron, no interviene un navegador, y no se si funcionaria Header Location de php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cron` to launch your PHP script via either command-line or with a workaround as a standard web script. If you want the latter you can just `wget http://localhost/whatever.php > /dev/null 2>&1`. Note the output redirection, because any output in processes lauched with cron will be mailed to the owner of the given crontab, so better suppress the output and log errors or notification separately.

Anyway, `crontab` allows for a one-minute interval between launches, so you shouldn't really have problems with your scripts timing out. Just make sure your script doesn't send more than 12-13 mails per launch (put a 5-second sleep between `mail()` calls) and you should do fine.